# Convert python2 shebang to python3 shebang for a set of files

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, upgrade, shebang

I upgraded my python scripts from version 2.7 to 3.6 - All the scripts have python2 shebang i.e., `#!/usr/bin/python`

I want to change it to python3 shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3` using a python script

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far? We can help you but not build anything for you!

Comment: @jonas thanks for your comment, I found a solution and have answered the question myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prerequisites:**

1. parseshebang - [`pip install parse-shebang`](https://pypi.org/project/parse-shebang/)
2. autopep8 - [`pip install autopep8`](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/)

**Libraries:**

```
import parseshebang
import os, sys
import subprocess
```

**Variables:**

```
pathToScripts = '/path/to/python/folder/'
maxLines = 5 # max empty lines before shebang occurs
replacementText = '#!/usr/bin/python3' #new shebang
```

**Function- replace_first_line:**

```
def replace_first_line( src_filename, target_filename, replacement_line):
    f = open(src_filename)
    first_line = f.readline()
    i = 0 
    while True:
        i+=1
        #check if the first line starts with a shebang
        if first_line.strip().startswith('#!'):
            break
        #check if the line is empty
        if first_line.strip() == '':
            #because line is empty, we read the next line
            first_line = f.readline()
            if first_line is None:
                #skip the file if there is nothing to read
                return
            if i >= maxLines:
                #The file contains more than 5 empty lines
                #Copy the file as it is
                break
    remainder = f.read()
    t = open(target_filename,"w")
    t.write(replacement_line + "\n")
    t.write(remainder)
    t.close()
```

**Main function:**

```
#Loop through all the .py files in the directory mentioned earlier
for file in [f for f in os.listdir(pathToScripts) if f.endswith('.py')]:
    shebang = parseshebang.parse(os.path.join(pathToScripts,file))
    if shebang and shebang[0] == replacementText.replace('#!',''):
        #The file already contains shebang, skip
        continue
    elif shebang:
        #if any shebang is present, replace the shebang with the new one
        #Note that we are sending the same path as source and target, 
        #so the changes will be overwritten - change accordingly
        replace_first_line(os.path.join(pathToScripts,file), os.path.join(pathToScripts,file), replacementText)

#to fix the tab error - inconsistent use of tabs
subprocess.call(['autopep8 --in-place --list-fixes --recursive ', pathToScripts], shell=True)
```

**FIN!**

*PS: This might be a cumbersome solution, but it definitely works. Please excuse me for my mistakes if any.*